# jQuery submit function on struts 1.x form

Tags: jquery, struts, form-submit

jQuery submit relies on the form having an id. With a struts `html:form` you cannot define the id, only a name.

```
$('form[name="uploadForm"]').submit(function() { 
     alert("submitting");
     // $('form[name="uploadForm"]').ajaxSubmit();
     return false; 
});
```

I've tried this, but the alert never shows up. Any ideas? The eventuality is to use the `ajaxSubmit` for a true AJAX form submit. But I'm just testing at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('form[name=uploadForm]').submit(function() { 
  alert("submitting");
  // $('form[name=uploadForm]').ajaxSubmit();
  return false; 
});
```